# Is there something similar in C# to fflush() from C?

Tags: c#, c, xaml, esri, fflush

My problem is:

The user can search an address. If there was nothing found, the user sees an messagebox. He can close it by pressing ENTER. So far, so good. Calling SearchAddresses() can also be started by hitting ENTER. And now the user is in an endless loop because every ENTER (to let the messagebox disappear) starts an new search.

Here the codebehind:

```
private void TxtBoxAddress_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
    }


private void queryTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        MessageBox.Show("*", "*", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        isMapNearZoomed = false;
    }
```

And here the xaml code:

```
<TextBox Background="Transparent" Name="TxtBoxAddress" Width="200" Text="" KeyUp="TxtBoxAddress_KeyUp"></TextBox>

<Button Content="Suchen" Name="btnSearch" Click="btnSearch_Click" Width="100"></Button>
```

How can I handle this endless loop in C#?

Comment: not sure what this has to do with fflush in C exactly?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. Please consider rephrasing and keep in mind that we don't know _anything_ about the problem. Also it seems that some parts of code is also missing.

Comment: Why not set the BtnSearch to be the Default button so that you don't have the logic in the textbox Key Up event?

Comment: @Anthony, I think the questioner wants to "flush" the "event buffer", so using the Enter key to dismiss the message box does not cause the search query to run again.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But that isn't what `fflush` does in C. (At least not in standard C.)

Comment: yes well.... this is all very confused. He needs a clearer dialog interface, maybe a [Search] and [Cancel] button ? Who knows It's not clear exactly what he is trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like the button you have is set as the default button so will automatically dismiss the dialog on typing enter.

Comment: Sorry, if it was vague. English is not my native language and I'm kinda in hurry, but I got a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lol. Thats a funny infinate loop. Theres lots of answers.

Try adding a global string, _lastValueSearched.

```
private string _lastValueSearched;

private void TxtBoxAddress_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && _lastValueSearched != TxtBoxAddress.Text)
      {
        //TxtBoxAddress.LoseFocus();
        btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
        _lastValueSearched = TxtBoxAddress.Text;
      }
  }


private void queryTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs e)
 {
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    MessageBox.Show("*", "*", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    isMapNearZoomed = false;
 }
```

So on the first enter insider the TxtBoxAddress, the lastSearchValue becomes the new search value. When they press enter on the messagebox, if the TxtBoxAddress text hasn't changed, the if statement will not trigger.

Alternativly, the line commented out, TxtBoxAddres.LoseFocus() may work by itself. This should take the focus off of the TextBox, so when the user presses enter on the messagebox, the TextBox KeyDown shouldn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Use `KeyPress` event instead of `KeyUp`:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13) // handle 'Enter' key
        MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Comment: Yes. just wanting to add: the problem is that the msgbox closes on keydown, and the key is still pressed when the focus changes back to the textbox, which then receives the keyup event, when you release the key.   but using a default button would be a much cleaner solution anyway.